# Angular ng-repeat performance issue, constantly updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am getting a very weird performance issue with `ng-repeat`. My repeat seems to be happening constantly, even with `track by`.

[image]

As you can see from the above gif, my `li` elements are constantly flashing inside dev tools (tested with Chrome dev tools and Firefox dev tools), meaning that the DOM elements are constantly being updated/repeated. This dramatically decreases the performance of my browser, and usually crashes Firefox.

Initially, there are only 10 `li` elements, although if the user scrolls down, I load another 10, hence being infinite scrolling. After around 3-4 loads (30-40 `li` elements), the browser becomes unresponsive.

I have noticed that the first `li` in the gif receives an `id` attribute of `id="sizzle1458257524957"` for a split second, then disappears. I have never seen this before, and it's definitely not coming from my own code. Not too sure if this is the culprit or not.

I tried adding a `$watch()` to my `postData` scope variable which the `ng-repeat` uses and then logging to see when it's updated, although it only ever gets updated twice, so I'm still baffled to why the `li` elements are always being updated.

It may be worth noting that I am using jQuery (2.2.0), but not for any event handlers on these elements. My angular version is 1.5.0.

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: Have you tried systematically removing the extra angular code in your markup? I dont think ngRepeat is the culprit. Also could you isolate the code in a demo? Would make it so I can debug.

Comment: @AlphaG33k & JanR - I'll try and isolate within a codepen or something now. It's just quite a large file, 1028 lines long. Will post a link in a few minutes if I can get it working.

Comment: What is this data-id and data-filter-class? Are you manipulating the DOM outside of Angular?

Comment: @AlphaG33k - Both attributes are being used by a jQuery library called `Wookmark`. Although I removed these elements and removed the initialisation of the plugin, but it did not solve my problem.

Comment: Ok figured it was worth mentioning. When you get the demo I'll take a crack

Comment: How'd you make the gif? That's cool.

Comment: Get a Plunker or a Code Example.. Plunker is prefered

Comment: @dwjohnston - Used Quicktime on my mac to record the screen. Trimmed it down to 4 seconds, then used an online video to gif converter.

Comment: @AlphaG33k - After spending around an hour trying to setup the demo in Codepen... I'm unable to reproduce the issue. Could something like this be coming from a filter? I removed all filters from the Codepen for simplicity, along with a few other little things.

Comment: @Fizzix It's hard to help you with above information. Please give us more details :)

Comment: If anyone is interested, I managed to solve this problem after 2 hours of investigating. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all that offered their help in solving this.

I managed to fix it after a ton of debugging and testing. The issue was with using a scope function within `ng-disabled` on a textarea within my `li` elements.

**This was the function:**

```
$scope.isCommentInputEmpty = function(commentPostId) {
    if($(".newsFeedPostItem[data-id='" + commentPostId + "']").find(".feedItemNewComment .taggableInput").val() === '') {
         return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

I then had a button with `ng-disabled="isCommentInputEmpty(post.id)"`

So I'm guessing that Angular runs that function almost constantly to check the textarea to see if it should be disabled or not.

To fix this, I simply added a model to my textarea, such as `ng-model="post.textareaModel"` and used `ng-disabled="post.textareaModel == ''"` to disable the button if the model is empty.